# How to execute the custom class added in the custom code

Tags: install4j

I need to execute the custom class added in the custom code resources. How could I do that. In InstallAnywhere we use CustomCode action in which we provide the jar of the custom code and the custom class. How to achieve the same in Install4j?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the JAR file on the "Installer->Custom Code & resources" step. Then add a "Run script" action to your installer. In the script, you can access all classes in the custom code.